# How to create a common jquery function and use that jquery function in click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button where on clicking the button it will clear all the textbox and drop down values now i need to create a common function 
and place my below jquery code in that common function so that i can call that function in button2,button3 click events of jquery

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" title="clear" id="btnclear" />
<input type="button" value="" title="clear" id="btn2" />
<input type="button" value="" title="clear" id="btn3" />
```

```js
// I need to place the below code in a function to use the function in remaining click events
$('#btnclear').off('click').on('click', function (RD) {
  $('#txtname').val("");
});

$("#btn2").click(function () {
  // I need to call the created common jquery function to clear the fields 
});

$("#btn3").click(function () {
  // I need to call the created common jquery function to clear the fields 
});
```

Comment: So create a function and call it...? If you're struggling try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: that i what my question is how to create a common function and place that common function in btn2 and btn3 click events of jquery

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a function in the normal way. Then you can call it from all the handlers:

```js
function clear_text() {
  $("#txtname").val("");
}
$('#btnclear').off('click').on('click', function() {
    clear_text();
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#tr2").show();
    clear_text();
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
    $("#tr2").hide();
    clear_text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Clear" title="clear" id="btnclear" />
<input type="button" value="" title="clear" id="btn2" />
<input type="button" value="" title="clear" id="btn3" /> Text: <input type="text" id="txtname">
```

Comment: then do i need to return clear_text() function in my html input tags <input type="button" value="" title="clear" id="btn2" />
<input type="button" value="" title="clear" id="btn3" />

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything different in the HTML.

Comment: Maybe you defined it inside a function scope and then tried to use it outside the function?

Comment: Make sure the event handlers are in the same scope where you put the function definition.

Comment: i have done the same as per your suggestion but its not working

Comment: @testuser I can't think of any reason why you would be getting that error. Check for typos.

Comment: function clear_text() {
           $('#btnclear').off('click').on('click', function (RD) {
           $('#txtname').val("");
  });
}


$("#btn2").click(function () {
clear_text();
});                                                                                                                     
this is what i did

Comment: That's not what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: You don't normally bind even handlers inside other event handlers.

Comment: My answer shows the way to do it. You're getting that error because you wrote something completely different.

Comment: but already in my btn2 and btn3 click events i am showing the hiding the fields  $("#btn2").click(function () {
if($(this).hasClass("buttonActive"))
{
$("#tr1").show();
$("#tr2").show();
}
else
{
clear_text(); //while hiding i am clearing the text in the fields
$("#tr1").hide();
$("#tr2").hide();
}
});  i am trying to clear the values before hiding the fields only